CREATE VIEW with sp_executesql Fails
I'm using Tiberius in Rust to execute a SQL command to create a view. The following command works perfectly when I run it directly in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but it fails when executed via sp_executesql in Tiberius.
This doesn't work via Tiberius:
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt=N'
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[abc] AS
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM table1
) AS document_path;', @params=N''

Error message:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'

But this works fine in SSMS:
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[abc] 
AS
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM 
        (SELECT col1, col2
         FROM table1) AS document_path;

Environment

SQL Server 2022
Rust: using Tiberius for SQL Server communication

Why does the command fail with sp_executesql in Tiberius, but works fine in SSMS? How can I make it work via sp_executesql?

The problem is you are passing a value for @params, which tells SQL Server there are parameters for the statement(s) you are passing it. If you have no parameters, you shouldn't pass a value for @params; it is not a required parameter.
If you remove the parameter, it works correctly:
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.objects;';

Even passing NULL for the parameter, causes the failure:
DECLARE @Params nvarchar(4000) = NULL;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.objects;', @Params;


Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.

The parameter, @params, must be entirely omitted.
